# How to fix Auto reloading of Vue App in browser without re-running the application in docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js

Please help, I kind of troubling my project with reloading the changes in my vue files. Changes in the webapp doesn't show upon refresh of page. What I need to do just to see the changes is to re-run the whole app with npm run serve.

My vue app is running inside a docker container.

Thanks for the help. It means so much.

Comment: What have you done up to now? How your Dockerfile look like? How do you start your application in docker? Is there any volume? Are you using nodemon?

Comment: I'm new in docker, but all I know is I'm running it in 8080 port, I mounted my project folder to the docker container. And when I change something in my vue project, it doesn't appear right away in the running browser, all I need to do just to see the changes is re run the vue application in the docker.